# Weird color ansi escape sequence behavior in while loop

Tags: python, ansi-escape, text-coloring

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game in Python. I thought it would be easier for the user if I made the Xs and Os colored. During gameplay, the first few iterations work fine, but then after a full row is in color, the string gets distorted and I can't figure out why.

The initial board is a string that I format like this:

```
def get_board():
   board = ""
   for i in range(9):
       if i == 1 or i == 4 or i == 7:
           board += f"  {i} |  {i+1} |  {i+2} \n"
       else:
           board += "    |" * 2 + "    \n"
       if i == 2 or i == 5:
           board += "- " * 7 + "-\n"
   return board
```

[image]

And then gameplay works like this:

```
def play_move(number, player, board):
   PURPLE = '\033[35m'
   YELLOW = '\033[33m'
   ENDC = '\033[0m'
   player = f"{PURPLE}{player}{ENDC}" if player == 'o' else f"{YELLOW}{player}{ENDC}"
   return board.replace(number, player)

def main():
   filled_spaces = []
   players = ["o", "x"]
   x = 0
   board = get_board()
   print(board)
   while x < 9:
       space = input(
           f"Enter a space on the board for player '{players[x%2]}'\n")
           board = play_move(space, players[x % 2], board)
           filled_spaces.append(space)
           x += 1
       print(board)
```

And then here's what happens

First round: o chooses 1

[image]

Second round: x chooses 2

[image]

Third round: o chooses 3

[image]

This is the full code if you want to try:

```
import sys


def get_board():
    board = ""
    for i in range(9):
        if i == 1 or i == 4 or i == 7:
            board += f"  {i} |  {i+1} |  {i+2} \n"
        else:
            board += "    |" * 2 + "    \n"
        if i == 2 or i == 5:
            board += "- " * 7 + "-\n"
    return board


def play_move(number, player, board):
    PURPLE = '\033[35m'
    YELLOW = '\033[33m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    player = f"{PURPLE}{player}{ENDC}" if player == 'o' else f"{YELLOW}{player}{ENDC}"
    return board.replace(number, player)


def main():
    filled_spaces = []
    players = ["o", "x"]
    x = 0
    board = get_board()
    print(board)
    while x < 9:
        space = input(
            f"Enter a space on the board for player '{players[x%2]}'\n")
        if space not in filled_spaces:
            board = play_move(space, players[x % 2], board)
            filled_spaces.append(space)
            x += 1
        else:
            print(
                f"\nERROR: {space} has already been taken, choose a different space\n")
        print(board, flush=True)

    print("GAME OVER")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: terminal buffering? What happens if you explicitly flush?

Comment: incidentally if it's a terminal problem you might be better off using a library for managing terminal output.  You'd hope they had tests for things like buffers.  Does it appear in all terminal apps?

Comment: @2e0byo, yeah it seems to be in all terminal apps. Tried it in the native terminal, VScode terminal and iTerm

Comment: I tried flush() before printing the new board in each iteration and it's still happening. Since I'm just looking for color, I imported Colorama to manage terminal output and that ended up being even worse. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: If you post a MRE (complete including imports) I'll see if I can duplicate tomorrow and if so look into it.  Weird problem btw.

Comment: Thanks, I added the full code at the bottome

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you are storing your codes in the grid.  After you store `"\033[35m"`, when you replace a 3 or a 5, you're also going to replace the digits in your ANSI codes, which destroys them.  You should leave the ANSI codes out of your grid, and just substitute them when you display.

Answer (score 2):

Let the grid just contain the moves, and do the formatting when you print:

```
import sys


def get_board():
    board = ""
    for i in range(9):
        if i == 1 or i == 4 or i == 7:
            board += f"  {i} |  {i+1} |  {i+2} \n"
        else:
            board += "    |" * 2 + "    \n"
        if i == 2 or i == 5:
            board += "- " * 7 + "-\n"
    return board

PURPLE = '\033[35m'
YELLOW = '\033[33m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'

def play_move(number, player, board):
    return board.replace(number, player)

def print_board(board):
    b = board.replace('o', f"{PURPLE}o{ENDC}").replace('x', f"{YELLOW}x{ENDC}")
    print(b)

def main():
    filled_spaces = []
    players = ["o", "x"]
    x = 0
    board = get_board()
    print_board(board)
    while x < 9:
        space = input(
            f"Enter a space on the board for player '{players[x%2]}'\n")
        if space not in filled_spaces:
            board = play_move(space, players[x % 2], board)
            filled_spaces.append(space)
            x += 1
        else:
            print(
                f"\nERROR: {space} has already been taken, choose a different space\n")
        print_board(board)

    print("GAME OVER")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```